# How to loop php using ref data from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, loops

How to loop php using ref data from mysql ?

work flow :

```
Loop If column 'xxx' == ''
{

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE xxx == '' order by id desc";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$datas=mysql_fetch_array($result);{
$id = stripslashes(str_replace('\r\n', '<br>',($datas['id'])));
}

$sql = "UPDATE table SET xxx = 'test' WHERE id = '$id' ";
$dbQuery = mysql_query($sql);'
}
```

Comment: What is `xxx` over here is it a variable

Comment: So how you're going to check if its not null if you don't have value of it

Comment: so, currently, your table ids are not integers? they have slashes? why?

Answer (score 1):

ypur query is confusing. why would you store ids with html in them? regardless, this should work

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE xxx != '' "; //ORDER BY will not work since ids are not int
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result){

    $id = stripslashes(str_replace('\r\n', '<br>',($row['id'])));

    $sql = "UPDATE table SET xxx = 'test' WHERE id = '$id' ";
    $dbQuery = mysql_query($sql);'
}
```